# Manually invoke MSLinqToSQLGenerator custom tool from a T4 file

Tags: templates, code-generation, t4

I am creating a *.tt file to automate some generation processes within my solution and am stuck at how to manually invoke the 'MSLinqToSQLGenerator' custom tool that LINQ uses. Can someone show me how this is done?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the alternative of replacing the default custom tool (that uses T4 internally) with a T4 that produces the same output?

I did it with this external template when I needed to plug in additional functionality.

[MSDN Documentation for the LINQ to SQL Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399400.aspx)

[Two Custom tool s for a single file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016083/two-custom-tool-s-for-a-single-file/6026252#6026252)

Comment: Where do I find the T4 that the default tool uses?

Comment: I tried again to find the default tool's T4, but I didn't (like I didn't before either). The community provided T4 can be verified to generate the same output; you can turn on the standard generator and simply compare the outcome. If they for some reason wouldn't match, you can alter the T4 yourself to meet the standard generator. MSDN only mention SQLMetal or ORM Designer [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399400.aspx)